Branch of ${\rm log}(z^2-1)$ on $\mathbb C\setminus[-1,1]$

Is it possible to define a branch of $\log\left(z^{2} - 1\right)$ on $\mathbb C\setminus\left[-1,1\right]$ ?.
If this is possible, is there any way to write some kind of formula for this branch, maybe in terms of the principal branch
$\operatorname{Log}\left(z\right)$ of $\log\left(z\right)$ ?.


Define $$f(z)=\int_{\sqrt{2}}^z\frac{2w}{w^2-1}dw$$ where the integral is taken over any path from $\sqrt{2}$ to $z$ in $\mathbb{C}\setminus[-1,1]$.
We want to show that this definition is independent of the path of integration from $z$ to $\sqrt{2}$. If we choose two paths of integration and we follow the first path from $\sqrt{2}$ to $z$, and the second path from $z$ back to $\sqrt{2}$ we get a closed contour. Note that the winding number $n$ of the points $w=1$ and $w=-1$ of such a closed contour must be the same. The residue theorem thus gives $$\int \frac{2w}{w^2-1}dw=2\pi in(1-1)=0$$ and the function $f$ is thus well defined.
Consider now $g(z)=\frac{e^{f(z)}}{z^2-1}$. Then $$g'(z)=\frac{e^{f(z)}f'(z)(z^2-1)-e^{f(z)}2z}{(z^2-1)^2}=0.$$ This shows that $g$ is constant. Furthermore $g(\sqrt{2})=\frac{e^0}1=1$ so $g(z)=1$ everywhere and it follows that $e^{f(z)}=z^2-1$.
